# Date time in java from SQL

Tags: java, mysql, date, jsp, time

I have this piece of code

```
while(activecheck.next()){
    Date status;
    String vincheck;
    Date curr = new Date();
    int datecheck;
    status = activecheck.getDate(8);
    vincheck = activecheck.getString(2);
    String update = "UPDATE Auctions SET status = '"+inactive+"' WHERE vin = '"+vincheck+"'";
    datecheck = status.compareTo(curr);

    if(datecheck < 0){  
        stmt6.executeUpdate(update);
    }
}
```

Which iterates through a mysql table checking for inactive bids. I am trying to check whether the date and time listed in the sql row has been passed by the current time. However, whenever I do this, it seems to only be comparing the dates, and not the times. What could be the cause of this?

This is the format I am using : **yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss**`

Comment: Your query is liable to sql injections. You should use prepared statements.

Comment: is there a reason we are updating RBAR (row by agonizing row)? and not just doing it in one fell swoop... `UPDATE Auctions SET status = 'inactive' WHERE col8 < NOW() AND ...` *whatever criteria is used in the* activecheck *cursor query* ...

Comment: Thanks for the concern but its just a school project

Comment: @spencer7593 no there is no reason, im just a noob and didnt know I could do it like that

Comment: [What does your step debugger tell you?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use type which is called Timestamp instead of the date. This way you will cover the date and the current time

```
  Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Comment: Still better, use `Instant` and `Instant.now()` and `activecheck.getObject(8, Instant.class)` and finally `if (status.isBefore(curr))`. Or possibly `LocalDateTime`, depending on the datatype of the database column.

Comment: Yes it certainly depends on what type is in the database column. @OleV.V.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome `java.sql.Timestamp` class was supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes, specifically [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html).

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
if( 
    myResultSet.getObject( … , Instant.class )  // Retrieve `Instant` (a moment in UTC) from database using JDBC 4.2 or later.
               .isBefore( Instant.now() )       // Comparing to the current moment captured in UTC.
)
{ 
    … 
}
```

## `java.util.Date` versus `java.sql.Date`

You may be confusing this pair of unfortunately mis-named classes. The first is a date-with-time type, in UTC. The second is a date-only type. Actually the second *pretends* to be a date-only type but actually has a time-of-day set to 00:00:00. Even worse, the second inherits from the first, but the documentation instructs us to ignore that fact.

Confusing? Yes. These awful classes are very poorly designed. Avoid them.

## java.time

You are using terribly troublesome old date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes.

### `Instant`

The `java.util.Date` class is replaced by `java.time.Instant`. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

### `LocalDate`

The `java.sql.Date` class is replaced by `java.time.LocalDate`. The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

### JDBC 4.2

As of JDBC 4.2 and later, you can directly exchange *java.time* classes with your database. No need to ever use java.sql or java.util date-time types again.

Tip: Make a habit of always using a [`PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) to avoid [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) risk. Not really any more work once you get used to it.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;  // Capture the current moment in UTC.
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , instant ) ;
```

And retrieval.

```
Instant instant = myResultSet.getObject( … , Instant.class ) ;
```

## Smart objects, not dumb strings

> This is the format I am using : yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`

Date-time values stored in a database do not have a “format”. Those values are stored by some internally-defined mechanism that does not concern us. They are *not* strings (not in any serious database, that is).

Your database, and your Java date-time objects, can *parse* a string representing a date-time value to create that value. And they can *generate* a string to represent that value. But the string and the date-time value are distinct and separate, and should not be conflated.

Use *java.time* objects to exchange date-time values with your database, not mere strings, just as you would for numbers and other data types your database comprehends. Use strings only for communicating textual values.

## Compare

To compare your retrieved values against the current moment, use the `isBefore`, `isAfter`, and `equals` methods of `Instant` class.

```
Instant now = Instant.now() ;
…
Instant instant = myResultSet.getObject( … , Instant.class ) ;
boolean isPast = instant.isBefore( now ) ;
if ( isPast ) { 
    … 
}
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).